# Mysql Connector C

Tags: c++, database, connector

I do not know English. I write to you with the help of an interpreter.
I have a problem. I can not solve it 6 days.
I use MySQL Connector C API and c++ to connect to the database.
The problem is that the compiled application displays an error when you run the query.
This request contains Cyrillic. Letters (А, Б, В, Г, Д...) - russian letters.

Here is an example implementation of my app:

```
0

1366
Incorrect string value: '\xCF\xE5\xF2\xF0' for column 'name' at row 1
```

**Now in more detail:**

**my.ini**

```
[client]
port        = 3306
default-character-set = utf8
character-sets-dir    = "C:\\Database\\mysql\\share\\charsets"

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8
character-sets-dir    = "C:\\Database\\mysql\\share\\charsets"

[mysqld]
basedir = "C:\\Database\\mysql"
datadir = "C:\\Database\\data"
character-set-server = utf8
character-sets-dir = "C:\\Database\\mysql\\share\\charsets"
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = "SET NAMES utf8"
port = 3306
log-error = errors.err
```

**Source code:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *host = "127.0.0.1";
    char *login = "root";
    char* pass = "12345";
    char* dbname = "documents";
    unsigned int port = 3306;

    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!(mysql_real_connect(conn, host, login, pass, dbname, port, NULL, 0)))
    {
        cout << "Error";
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_query(conn, "SET NAMES utf8");

    cout << mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
    cout << mysql_error(conn) << endl;


    mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO person VALUES('Петр')");
    //mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES ('Petr')");

    cout << mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
    cout << mysql_error(conn) << endl;

    mysql_close(conn);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

here note the line:

```
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES ('Petr')");
```

s line is successful, the result:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| Petr |
+------+
```

line

```
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO person VALUES('Петр')");
```

the following line is successful only if the string

```
mysql_query(conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

comment on. the result will be as follows:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| Ïåòð |
+------+
```

[image]

but if the line

```
mysql_query(conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

not commented.an error will occur at the beginning, said post (picture).

Next...

**Setting mysql**

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                             |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                              |
| character_set_connection | utf8                              |
| character_set_database   | utf8                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                            |
| character_set_results    | utf8                              |
| character_set_server     | utf8                              |
| character_set_system     | utf8                              |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Database\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%colla%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set, 5 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql>


mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for Win32 (AMD64)

Connection id:          12
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 14 min 22 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 70  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 117  Flush tables: 1  Open ta
bles: 110  Queries per second avg: 0.081
--------------

mysql>
```

I tried using utf8mb4, but it occurred the same problem.
I'm at a loss.
cp1251 but works correctly, but I need it utf8.
I saw many posts on this resource. 
I have not found the solution to his problems.

please help.

PS. source code encoding utf8

Comment: Are you using connector that supports Unicode or Multi-byte characters?  I'm presently working on rebuilding the connector and MySql Server for Unicode.

Comment: I use the connector supplied with the mysql 5.7.11. project compile how "Use Unicode Character Set" (VS C++)

Comment: Thomas Matthews. I followed your link and change your code, I wrote a line: `mysql_options(conn, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");
 mysql_options(conn, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8");                                                                     ` after mysql_init() before mysq_real_connect(). the error is not gone

Comment: I laid request SET NAMES utf8 on subqueries: character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection. It is a request character_set_connection generates an error. if we exclude it, I get characters ?????. but the error does not occur